# Error C2228: left of '.visitFile' must have class/struct/union type

Tags: c++

#### Visitor.h

```
class Visitor{
public:
    virtual ~Visitor() {}
    virtual void visitNode(Node*) = 0;
    virtual void visitFile(File*) = 0;
    virtual void visitDirectory(Directory*) = 0;
    virtual void visitLink(Link*) = 0;
protected:
    Visitor();
    Visitor(const Visitor&);
};
//realize those visit function
void Visitor::visitNode(Node* n) {
    //common default behavior
    cerr << "It is not a directory! " << endl;
}
void Visitor::visitDirectory(Directory* d) {
    Visitor::visitNode(d);
}
void Visitor::visitFile(File* f) {
    Visitor::visitNode(f);
}
void Visitor::visitLink(Link* l) {
    Visitor::visitNode(l);
}
```

#### File.h

```
class File : public Node {
public:
    File();
    //redeclare common interface here
    void setName(string& name);
    string& getName();
    void setCDate(char* cDate);
    char* getCDate();
    long size();
    virtual void accept(Visitor*) = 0;
private:
    string& name;
    char* cDate;
};
//realize the function accept
void File::accept(Visitor* v) {
    v.visitFile(this);
}
```

The problem is the function `accept(Visitor* v){}`, my compiler always tell me:

```
d:\win7 data\data\c\filemanage\file.h(20) : error C2228: left of '.visitFile' must have class/struct/union type
```

How can I deal with it?

Comment: It isn't clear how the code in `File.h` knows what a `Visitor` is; in fact, given the compiler warnings, it probably doesn't know what a `Visitor` is.  You need to include `Visitor.h` in `File.h` (and you'll need include guards around the material in both headers) so that the compiler knows what a `Visitor` is.  However, I would have expected more complaints at the `virtual void accept(Visitor *) = 0;` line.

Answer (score 2):

`v` is a pointer, should call `operator->` and should be `*this`

```
void File::accept(Visitor* v) {
    v->visitFile(*this);
//   ^^          ^
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, however, my compiler tell me:error C2227: left of '->visitFile' must point to class/struct/union,how can I deal with it?

Comment: Does File.h include Visitor.h?